# Windows machine Installing pycurl module on Thonny

Tags: python, windows, pycurl

I am trying to install pycurl module in Thonny virtual environment but without any luck..
Whatever I try, I am getting the same error message:

```
Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
```

I have previously installed this module on my Raspberry PI linux and did not have any issues whatsoever. Seems like a lot of people are having issues installing it on Windows Machine and there is still no clear solution to this.

1. According to the official pycurl website:
   http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#windows

I should be able to install pycurl by using pip install pycurl. That is not the case unfortunately.

2. Also, they provide a link that is not working:
   [image]

Clicking on the link returns  "Forbidden".

Hoping to get some clarification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install the current version, you need to build it from source.

You may be able to find a binary of a previous version to install through pypi.